# AnnotationView open when searching

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, mkmapview

I have a map search controller that when I search for some annotation, its zooming on it .
Also I would like that when I press the result it will zoom on the correct pin and automatically open the annotationView of the specific annotation

here is my code :

https://github.com/hellzkitchen/stackoverflow-041917.git

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController {

    var matchingItems = [CustomAnnotations]()
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil

    var handleMapSearchDelegate:HandleMapSearch? = nil

    func parseAddress(selectedItem:MKPlacemark) -> String {
        // put a space between "4" and "Melrose Place"
        let firstSpace = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil && selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) ? " " : ""
        // put a comma between street and city/state
        let comma = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil || selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) && (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil || selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? ", " : ""
        // put a space between "Washington" and "DC"
        let secondSpace = (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil && selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? " " : ""
        let addressLine = String(
            format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
            // street number
            selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
            firstSpace,
            // street name
            selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
            comma,
            // city
            selectedItem.locality ?? "",
            secondSpace,
            // state
            selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
        )
        return addressLine
    }

    func search(keywords:String) {
        self.matchingItems.removeAll()
        for annotation in self.mapView!.annotations {
            if annotation.isKindOfClass(CustomAnnotations) {
                //Just an example here for searching annotation by title, you could add other filtering actions else.
                if (annotation.title??.rangeOfString(keywords) != nil) {
                    self.matchingItems.append(annotation as! CustomAnnotations)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.startWithCompletionHandler { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matchingItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapSearchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = selectedItem.subtitle
        return cell
    }

}


extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row]//.placemark
        handleMapSearchDelegate?.dropPinZoomIn(selectedItem)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you search for a designated annotation, there is a method `selectAnnotation:` 
So when you tap on that result, use

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(resultAnnotation, animated: true)
```

Comment: I will check it when Il be home.   I need to put it into my mapviewcontroller?